# to convert a MCQ in the required format - python

Tags: python, regex, file

I am trying to convert MCQ which is as follows:

```
Which will legally declare, construct, and initialize an array?
A. int [] myList = {"1", "2", "3"};
B. int [] myList = (5, 8, 2);
C. int myList [] [] = {4,9,7,0};
D. int myList [] = {4, 3, 7};
ANSWER: D
```

into the required format which is as mentioned below:

```
Which will legally declare, construct, and initialize an array?
int [] myList = {"1", "2", "3"};
int [] myList = (5, 8, 2);
int myList [] [] = {4,9,7,0};
*int myList [] = {4, 3, 7};
```

The logic I'm trying is as follows:

```
1. Open the text file and trying to fetch the line number of "ANSWER: D"
2. Open the file again and go to that line number
3. write a for loop which will iterate max 5 times till it find the match 
   "D." is found.
4.Once the match is found replace it with '*'
```

Below is the code I tried:

```
import re

ans = []
line_no = []

class Options:
  def __init__(self, ans1, num1):
    self.a = ans1
    self.n = num1
    #print(self.a, self.n)


pattern = 'ANSWER: [A-Z]' # to fetch the answer of each question
r = re.compile(pattern)

pattern1 = '[A-F]\.\s'
re1 = re.compile(pattern1)



with open (r"C:\Users\dhvani\Desktop\test.txt", "r") as f:
 for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
    d = r.findall(line)
    if(d):
        l = d[0].split(":")
        m = l[1].split(" ")
        m = m[1] + "."
        ans.append(m)
        line_no.append(num)

x = Options(ans, line_no)
print(x.a, x.n)



with open (r"C:\Users\dhvani\Desktop\test.txt", "r") as f:
  for i, j in enumerate(ans):
     j1 = j[0]
     z = f.readlines()[j1 - 1]
     print(z)
     for n in range(j1 - 1, j1 - 7, -1):
         value = f.readline()
         value1 = re1.findall(value)

         if value1:
             if value1 == i:
                 value.sub('[A-F]\.\s', '*', value)
         break;
```

I am able to fetch the line number of "ANSWER: D" and store 'D.' and its corresponding line number in two different lists.

Then later steps are unsuccessful.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
I am new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code: reading from a file, doing required modifications and writing them into a new text file.

```
import re

with open("your_filename_here", "r") as fp:
    string = fp.read()
    f1 = open(r"your_filename_here", "w")

    rx = re.compile(r'''
                (?!^[A-E]\.)
                (?P<question>.+[\n\r])
                (?P<choices>[\s\S]+?)
                ^ANSWER:\ (?P<answer>[A-E])
                ''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

    rq = re.compile(r'^[A-E]\.\ (?P<choice>.+)')

    for match in rx.finditer(string):

        def repl(line, answer):
            if line.startswith(answer):
                line = rq.sub(r"*\1", line)
            else:
                line = rq.sub(r"\1", line)
            return line

        lines = [repl(line, match.group('answer')) 
                for line in match.group('choices').split("\n") 
                if line]

        block = match.group('question') + "\n".join(lines)
        #print(block)
        f1.write(block + "\n\n")
```

This splits your blocks into parts of question, choices and the answer and analyzes them afterwards. See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/Mvp0PE).

Comment: Thanks alot Sir. The input is a text file. Can you assist me in which line of code I should insert the file open command?

Comment: I should do the above process for 1600 MCQs.

Comment: Done with reading and writing the required format in a text file. Adding two lines before string = " your-string"                                                                       with open (r"your-file-path", "r") as f:
        string = f.read()
        f1 = open(r"your-file-path", "w")  and at the end;           f1.write(block + "\n\n")                                                                                                     Thank you Sir for your great help

Comment: @DhvaniShah: See the updated abswer with `with open...`